# Delay when downloading with SourceForge and many other sites

Tags: distribution, monetization, publishing

When I am downloading a file with SourceForge, and also from many other sites, I'm getting a count down and I am wondering what is the reason?

[image: download delay]

I'm not talking about storage sites like rapidgator, etc that are trying to promote their premium services, but free sites like SourceForge.

Comment: This is not really a question about open source software.

Comment: @Brandin, I think questions about the functionality of web sites used to share open source projects would be relevant to the open source subject. The topic is rather broad is rather broad and distribution is part of it.

Comment: As a strategy for monetisation I think it qualifies as on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advertising, to pay for the free service.

To the right of the `Downloading in....` message you will also find `Mirror Provided by:` and `Scanned by:`, while I doubt these are paid ads, it would be in return for providing the mirror/scan service, underneath you will find paid ads under the `You may like:`. Then under that, you have other top projects in the same category so that you may keep looking and download something else, to get more ads.

By making you keep the page open for a few seconds, they have time to display ads that might get your attention and increase the chance of revenue from you clicking an ad.